# Forcing a transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am writing a script that needs to loop over a table and insert values into an other tabel.

The problem is that some duplicate values occur when linking data before inserting it into the new table.

I am doing this in a while loop and it looks to me like SQLServer is building up all insert statements in memory and executes them when the script is finished.

Is the feeling I got correct and if so, is there a way to force SQLServer to perform every transaction individually when they occur in the code?

Comment: SQL Server normally commits after every `insert` statement -- unless you are inside a transaction.

Comment: Why are you using a loop to insert data? Whatever you are doing is sounds like it should be a single insert statement. Can you share your code?

Comment: I presume being inside a while loop or if statement is not considered a transaction, meaning my code (logic) is the issue? I would rather not share the code and learn by fixing the issue myself, researching what could be the issue and going trough the process of illumination.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking (but not always), when you receive duplicate records, there is an issue with your logic. That said, use **select distinct** to remove duplicates.

```
Insert into tablec (a, b, c)
select distinct  tablea.a, tablea.b, tableb.c 
  from tablea
left outer join tableb on tablea.a = tableb.b
```